# Oracle creating random count of rows per employee

Tags: oracle, sqlite, random, cartesian-product

Can someone provide a solution that populates the access_history table with a random count of employees, with a random list of locations and a random date.

I provided a detailed test case to generate random employees and locations records.

I got the INSERT working but it always generates a fixed number(20) of records for each employee where I want a random number of records for each employee ie 1, 12, 7, 19, 20, 4,....

```
ALTER SESSION SET.  NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'MMDDYYYY HH24:MI:SS';

-- create and populate an employee 
-- table with 50 rows

CREATE TABLE employees AS
SELECT level AS employee_id,

CASE round(dbms_random.value(1,20)) 
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Albert' 
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Tom' 
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Anna'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'Ty' 
        WHEN 5 THEN 'Andy' 
        WHEN 6 THEN 'Thomas' 
        WHEN 7 THEN 'Alan'
        WHEN 8 THEN 'Tara' 
        WHEN 9 THEN 'Cheryl' 
        WHEN 10 THEN 'Ed' 
        WHEN 11 THEN 'Steve'
        WHEN 12 THEN 'Mel' 
        WHEN 13 THEN 'Micheal' 
        WHEN 14 THEN 'Ron' 
        WHEN 15 THEN 'Donald'
        WHEN 16 THEN 'Donny' 
        WHEN 17 THEN 'Racheal' 
        WHEN 18 THEN 'Debbie' 
        WHEN 19 THEN 'Madison'
        WHEN  20 THEN 'Danny' 
     END AS first_name,

CASE  round(dbms_random.value(1,20)) 
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Andrews' 
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Thorton' 
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Smith'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'Jones' 
        WHEN 5 THEN 'Ott' 
        WHEN 6 THEN 'Stevens' 
        WHEN 7 THEN 'Feldman'
        WHEN 8 THEN 'Stein' 
        WHEN 9 THEN 'Ross' 
        WHEN 10 THEN 'Eden' 
        WHEN 11 THEN 'Saltzman'
        WHEN 12 THEN 'Kramer'
        WHEN 13 THEN 'Monroe' 
        WHEN 14 THEN 'Hanks' 
        WHEN 15 THEN 'Dunn'
        WHEN 16 THEN 'Dunbar' 
        WHEN 17 THEN 'Rucker' 
        WHEN 18 THEN 'Silverberg' 
        WHEN 19 THEN 'Daniels'
        WHEN  20 THEN 'Kahn' 
     END AS last_name, 
    
dbms_random.string('X',        dbms_random.value(5, 10))  AS card_num

FROM   dual
CONNECT BY level <= 50;


ALTER TABLE employees
     ADD ( CONSTRAINT employee_id_pk
   PRIMARY KEY (employee_id));

-- create and populate a location 
-- table with 10 rows. Randomly
-- make some types 'A' for access
-- 'T' for time and attendance,
-- 'G' for guard tour.

CREATE TABLE locations AS
SELECT level AS location_id,
   'Door ' || level AS location_name,

CASE round(dbms_random.value(1,3)) 
        WHEN 1 THEN 'A' 
        WHEN 2 THEN 'T' 
        WHEN 3 THEN 'G' 
     END AS location_type

FROM   dual
CONNECT BY level <= 25;


 ALTER TABLE locations 
     ADD ( CONSTRAINT location_id_pk
   PRIMARY KEY (location_id));


create table access_history(
   employee_id NUMBER(6), 
   card_num varchar2(10),
   location_id number(4),
   access_date date,
   processed NUMBER(1) default 0
);



INSERT into access_history
 (employee_id,
   card_num,
  location_id,
   access_date)
   with all_combos as
      ( select e.*, l.*
      from   employees e, locations l
     )
    select *
     from (
       select employee_id, card_num,
               location_id, 
             trunc(sysdate) +     dbms_random.value (0, 2) + dbms_random.value (0, .75)
        from   all_combos
        order by dbms_random.value
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dbms_random`. To give simple example:

```
Select * from
(Select e.*,
       Row_number() over (partition by e.emp_id order by dbms_random.value(0,1)) as rn,
       Count(1) over (partition by e.emp_id) as cnt
  From employees e)
Where dbms_random.value(0,1) * cnt >= rn 
   Or rn = 1 -- to ensure that one record per employee is selcted.
```

Comment: Can you put your solution within my example. Why order by dbms_random.value(0,1) if I choose (1,20) will that ensure I get at least 1 record per employee eliminating the need for the 'OR' predicate. I appreciate your help and expertise

Comment: Your example is quite complicated to understand so I just eased it out. and you can twist it as per your requirement but I think given solution with OR will be better to understand and makes the clear solution.

Comment: After I combine the contents of both tables your suggestion is to add your code Row_number() over (partition by e.emp_id order by dbms_random.value(0,1)) as rn,
       Count(1) over (partition by e.emp_id) as cnt
  From employees e) at that point

Comment: Yes, That is what I suggest!! :)

Comment: Thanks for your help but I'm struggling to INSERT the code into my test case, i get view doesn't exist.